# Show two plots of different natures in same figure with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot two different plots (one is a simple figure generated by a matrix with a color scale) and the other is a graph with x and y axes from a group of points that represents an skeleton. The matrix color scale is associated with the skeleton graph. It must be shown n times in a loop, at each time that the canvas is closed, then next plot shows.

But I'm only being capable of showing each figure at once, for example,let's say that I must have 43 canvas each one with a graph and a color scale matrix side by  side, instead I'm getting 86 plots, one from the dots graph, the next for the scale matrix, and so on.

The code is below, and so the pictures of each plot. I'm using gridspec to generate the graph, and a simple imgplot to generate the color scale matrix.

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np
import sys
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


movimento = np.loadtxt("file01.txt")
qtd_posturas = int(len(movimento)/20)


c = 0
lista = []
for i in range(qtd_posturas):
lista.append(movimento[(i*20):((i+1)*20),:3]) 

matrixCoord = np.array(lista)


matrixDistance= np.zeros((qtd_posturas,20,20))
for k in range(qtd_posturas):
    for i in range(len(matrixDistance[0])):
        for j in range(len(matrixDistance[0])):
        matrixDistance[k,i,j] = np.linalg.norm(matrixCoord[k,i,:] -         matrixCoord[k,j,:])

num_plots = qtd_posturas
z = 0
for m in range(num_plots):
  img = matrixDistance[m]
  imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
  imgplot.set_cmap('PuBu')
  plt.colorbar()
  plt.show()
  z += 20
  esqueleto = movimento[:z,:2]
  x = esqueleto[:,0]
  y = -esqueleto[:,1]
  gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, width_ratios=[3, 1]) 
  plt.figure()
  plt.subplot(gs[1])
  plt.scatter(x,y, s=50)
  plt.title('Esqueleto')
  plt.show()
```

Images:

[image]
[image]

Comment: In the `for` loop you create a new figure at each iteration via `plt.figure()`. Why would you do that? That takes you to a new figure and so you'll twice as many as iterations. Also when looking at the plots, the axes scales don't match so you'll have trouble fitting them on the same axis. Either you need to create new axes or rescale one of them to fit on the existing axis.

Comment: That's what I'm having problems with, I don't know how to reconfigure it properly.

Comment: You don't plot the `imshow` image in the figure with subplots...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the figure with subplots at the start of the loop, then plot the graphs in the respective subplots:

```
for m in range(num_plots):
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, width_ratios=[3, 1])  # create figure at start of loop

    img = matrixDistance[m]
    plt.subplot(gs[0])  # first subplot
    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
    imgplot.set_cmap('PuBu')
    plt.colorbar()

    z += 20
    esqueleto = movimento[:z,:2]
    x = esqueleto[:,0]
    y = -esqueleto[:,1]
    plt.subplot(gs[1])  # second subplot
    plt.scatter(x,y, s=50)
    plt.title('Esqueleto')
    plt.show()
```